# Design pattern for encapsulation of functions that draw / write an object

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, design-principles

My specific case is a web application but I believe this would apply more generally:

I have data stored remotely in a database.

My application uses 'collection' objects that correspond to each table in the database and manage database interactions for that table. The collection object contains an array of 'row' objects corresponding to each row of data.

The collection and row objects are responsible for writing themselves to the page (in HTML) when requested ie. the collection table sets up the table and table headers (`<table>,<thead>,<tbody>`) and then tells each row in turn to write itself (`<tr>,<td>`).

All is working well, it's just starting to get unwieldy. The row object for example has more than 1000 lines of code to handle displaying different data types (radio buttons, checkboxes, images etc) as well as handling user interaction, validating data and dealing with image/file uploads.

I'd like to separate the code out so that display behaviours live in one place and interaction / data management behaviours live in another.

Do I:

1. Keep the object structure 'as is' but have separate files containing the different types of behaviours eg. collection.js and collection_displayBehaviours.js
2. Create a separate object class eg. 'htmlTableConstructor.js' that handles the production of html elements
3. ?? Is there some approach I'm missing?

Comment: "collection' objects that correspond to each table in the database" -- this sounds like an ORM.

Comment: The whole thing you're describing seems to be an MVC framework, there are many professionally written ones to choose.

Comment: 1_000 rows!? Tomorrow 10_000+? What about pagination?..

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan indeed, the collection object handles pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on "refactoring"; and I'd start with  "replacing switch statements with polymorphism". That's how to extract the "if type of data is 'sale-record' draw it this way" logic into a saleRecord class that includes a draw() method that knows how to render it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. My situation is more 'if data type is a dropdown draw it this way', 'if data type is free text draw it this way' etc. but I could make a data point protocol and have the different types of data point conform to that protocol. Thanks.